# How to unit test complex logic in RxJava operators?

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java, rx-android

I am struggling with how to test complex logic in RxJava streams that have many operators. I'm finding that if I have complex logic and many operators with complex logic strung together that unit testing the stream becomes a nightmare because there are so many combinations of cases to cover.

Here is an example of what I'm describing:

```
        Observable<ObjectA> observable = myRepository
            .fetchA()
            .flatMap(new Func1<ObjectA, Observable<ObjectA>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<ObjectA> call(final ObjectA object) {
                    if (object.isAvailable()) {
                        //do something
                        return myRepository
                                .fetchAnotherThing();
                    } else {
                        //do something else
                        return myRepositor
                                .fetchADifferentThing();
                    }
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<ObjectA, Observable<ObjectA>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<ObjectA> call(final ObjectA object) {
                    if (object.isFull()) {
                        //do something
                        return myRepository
                                .doThingA();
                    } else {
                        //do something else
                        return myRepository
                                .doThingB();
                    }
                }
            });
```

If I want to write a unit test for this I would need to write at least 4 test methods so that I could cover all combinations of the conditional logic.

Usually when something like this happens I'd write a custom class to handle the logic and then unit test that class. So the above code might turn into something like this:

```
public class MyFunc implements Func1<ObjectA, Observable<ObjectA>> {
    @Override
    public Observable<ObjectA> call(final ObjectA object) {
        //The logic that was formerly in an anonymous Func1 is now here
        if (object.isAvailable()) {
            //do something
            return myRepository.fetchAnotherThing();
        } else {
            //do something else
            return myRepository.fetchADifferentThing();
        }
    }
}

public class MyOtherFunc implements Func1<ObjectA, Observable<ObjectA>> {
    @Override
    public Observable<ObjectA> call(final ObjectA object) {
        //The logic that was formerly in an anonymous Func1 is now here
        if (object.isFull()) {
            //do something
            return myRepository.doThingA();
        } else {
            //do something else
            return myRepository.doThingB();
        }
    }
}
```

Now MyFunc and MyOtherFunc are now unit testable by themselves and I can verify that the logic is correct in isolation. Then my original code could be transformed into something like this:

```
Observable<ObjectA> observable = myRepository
            .fetchA()
            .flatMap(myFunc)
            .flatMap(myOtherFunc);
```

That certainly looks more concise and alleviates the need for my unit test of the chain to handle many cases as it did before, but now the question is how do I test what's left?

If I mock the output of myFunc and myOtherFunc then it seem like I'm not really testing anything at all. Another option would be to use real implementations of myFunc and myOtherFunc but now I'm not doing a unit test anymore I'm doing an integration test and that comes with extra hassles.

Has anyone else struggled with this before and if so how did you solve your problems of testability?

Comment: If you create mocks for `myFunc` and `myOtherFunc`, then you can test for variations on a) timing, b) error conditions, c) parallelism, d) composition. For instance, what happens when `fetchA()` emits more than one item? No items?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems reasonable, especially if you want to separate the units under test into their own classes. But just leaving the code as is would be fine too, as long as it's not more complex than what you have.

But if the logic inside your `flatMap`'s does grow more complex, you might consider moving that code to separate methods, like this:

```
class ClassUnderTest {
  private MyRepository myRepository;

  public void doSomething() {
    Observable<ObjectA> observable = myRepository
      .fetchA()
      .flatMap(new Func1<ObjectA, Observable<ObjectA>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<ObjectA> call(final ObjectA object) {
          return getMoreThings(object);
        }
      })
      .flatMap(new Func1<ObjectA, Observable<ObjectA>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<ObjectA> call(final ObjectA object) {
          return doThings(object);
        }
      });
  }

  Observable<ObjectA> doThings(ObjectA object) {
    if (object.isFull()) {
      //do something
      return myRepository.doThingA();
    } else {
      //do something else
      return myRepository.doThingB();
    }
  }

  Observable<ObjectA> getMoreThings(ObjectA object) {
    if (object.isAvailable()) {
      //do something
      return myRepository.fetchAnotherThing();
    } else {
      //do something else
      return myRepository.fetchADifferentThing();
    }
  }
```

Or you can chain observables in this fashion:

```
class ClassUnderTest2 {
  private MyRepository myRepository;

  public void doSomething() {
    Observable<ObjectA> fetchAsync = myRepository.fetchA();
    Observable<ObjectA> fetchMoreAsync = getFetchMoreAsync(fetchAsync);
    Observable<ObjectA> doThingsAsync = getDoThingsAsync(fetchMoreAsync);
  }

  Observable<ObjectA> getFetchMoreAsync(Observable<ObjectA> fetchAsync) {
    return fetchAsync
      .flatMap(new Func1<ObjectA, Observable<ObjectA>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<ObjectA> call(final ObjectA object) {
          if (object.isAvailable()) {
            //do something
            return myRepository.fetchAnotherThing();
          } else {
            //do something else
            return myRepository.fetchADifferentThing();
          }
        }
      });
  }

  Observable<ObjectA> getDoThingsAsync(Observable<ObjectA> fetchMoreAsync) {
    return fetchMoreAsync
      .flatMap(new Func1<ObjectA, Observable<ObjectA>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<ObjectA> call(final ObjectA object) {
          if (object.isFull()) {
            //do something
            return myRepository.doThingA();
          } else {
            //do something else
            return myRepository.doThingB();
          }
        }
      });
  }
}
```

In both examples you'll be able to test the behavior independent of the full Observable stream.